# How to convert Navigable String to File Object

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from a website (using the modules named `requests` & `BeautifulSoup`) and print it in a text file but every time I try to do so, it says the following:

> TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'NavigableString'

I have tried using the csv library to import the data but since I couldn't add the line by line data to the csv, I decided to add all the output to a text file and then take out the data I require.

```py
file_object = open("name-list.txt", "w") #Opening the file

name = soup.find(class_='table-responsive') #Extracting the data
name_list = name.find_all('td') #Refining the data

for final in name_list:
    all = final.contents[0] #Final result
    file.write(all) #This is where the Error Comes

file.close()
```

When I use `print(all)` in the for loop, I get the output that I need which consists of multi-line text including the names, age, gender, etc. of the people from the table on the website but when I try to print that output into the text file, the error pops up.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your data?

Comment: @Jkind9 Structure like how? I mean like an example or the name, age, gender, etc.?

Comment: where do you assign to `file`? it looks like you actually want to be writing to `file_object`

Comment: Actually, I solved it on my own. But just in case I run into this error in future, I'll answer that question. So, umm, this is what exactly I am trying to do. Suppose there's a website that has names, ages, gender, and income of people. Now I extracted the data from the website into a form like this ( assume ' ; ' as next line )

Ishaan Pathak;
19;
Male;
10 Lakhs; (Just an Example XD)

Now I want to extract the names and ages of people and store them into a text file which I will use in another program.